# DB2 2 Slow Authentication / Connection Establish

Tags: active-directory, db2

I have a DB2 server installed on Windows 2008, and found that the local OS users are instantly authenticated, but the server take a long time to authenticate LDAP (AD) users, more than 3 minutes but it will success. If i provide the wrong password, the authentication fails immediately.

Does anyone know if there any settings that make can tune the authentication process?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by running this command: db2set -g DB2_GRP_LOOKUP=local

Comment: Glad you fixed it. Please mark this "accepted" when you are able.